# Install/distribute a Specific Version of CPython Interpreter and Dependent Modules Along With My Script to Customers

Tags: python, installation

I have a fairly complex Python application that I want to install on customers' computers. I am thinking to install a private copy of the python interpreter and the libraries along with my scripts. Is there any way to do this?

Note that I am not looking for pyexe/pyinstaller kind of solution. Such a solution creates a giant executable containing the interpreter, the libraries, and my scripts. When it runs it dynamically retrieves everything and starts the script. I cannot use such solution because my script runs my other scripts by spawning subprocesses. There are so many subprocesses I spawn that it will be prohibitively slow if I freeze the subprocesses into an exe file, as it usually takes a long to start due to the unfreezing every time a subprocess is spawned.

What I am looking for is a way to install my python scripts along with a private copy of the interpreter and libraries. I am hoping that I can create an installer to do the job. The installer will just install all the necessary files to a directory and ideally will create an icon on the desktop.

It is clearly possible. I was looking at the WingIDE. It is very possible that it was built in python but distributes a frozen version of python with it.

BTW: I am using windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [PortablePython](http://www.portablePython.com)  .  It's self contained and has no registry dependencies. You will probably need to set up a sitecustomize.py that points at your application and possible also block a system level PythonPath variable to avoid running code from another install

Comment: That's certainly one way. I have checked out PortablePython. One problem appears that it might be a bit tricky to install new libraries not included with it. Some blogs suggest that easy_install will be fine, but it is not clear that modules that cannot be installed with easy_install will be fine. But it's not clear modules that cannot be handled by easy_install will be fine.

Comment: I've had pretty good luck with easy_install, and where that did not work manual installation to the site_packages in my PortablePython directory.  In my application this is distributed to users who are all synced to a the same perforce directory so I only maintain the one copy and everybody gets that (no installer, but of course you have to be on our perforce.) I haven't seen any significant differences from standard windows python - i've distributed QT and the perforce api, which both include compiled PYDs, this way.